# when we initialize actor system and create an actor using actorOf method, how many actors are getting created?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have 2 questions:

- How many actors does the below code create?
- How do I create 1000 actors at the same time?

```
val system = ActorSystem("DonutStoreActorSystem");
val donutInfoActor = system.actorOf(Props[DonutInfoActor], name = "DonutInfoActor")
```

Comment: One actor is created. Please add more info to the question so it can be clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: `How do I create 1000 actors at the same time?` Use foor loop and give them different names by postfix index

Answer (score 0):

When you start the classic actor system and use `actorOf` like that it will create one of your `DonutInfoActor` and a few internal Akka system actors related to the event bus, logging, cluster if you are using that.

Just as texasbruce said in a comment, a loop lets you create any number of actors from a single spot, startup is async, so you will get an `ActorRef` back that is ready to use but the actor that it referencing it may still be starting up.

Note that if you are building something new we recommend the new "typed" actor APIs that was completed in Akka 2.6 over the classic API used in your sample.